# How to start an activity and display it inside the parent activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

**In short:**
Can I start another Activity in the onCreate() of my MainActivity and display the newly created Activity in the MainActivity's layout?

I want to start a view (DecoratedBarcodeView) right at the start of the MainActivity. My layout looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizont">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:onClick="pause" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resume"
            android:onClick="resume" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know I could start an activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But for that I would need a class `CustomActivity` which I want to get rid of and place its contents into the MainActivity.

Its onCreate() method looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        barcodeView = (DecoratedBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
        Collection<BarcodeFormat> formats = Arrays.asList(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
        barcodeView.getBarcodeView().setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(formats));
        barcodeView.initializeFromIntent(getIntent());
        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);
    }
```

So essentially I want to do this `barCodeView.decodeContinuous(callback)` from within my MainActivity. But To do that I apparently need an Intent.

So what is the best approach to start an Activity and display it inside my MainActivity?

Comment: You can't start Activity inside another one, it is android ecosystem limits, you can't change it. But you can use Fragments instead of that. Check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: But when I start an Activity from inside a Fragment, what would I have gained? The whole screen becomes that newly started Activity which is what I don't want.

Comment: @Sadik Not "start an Activity from a Fragment". The CustomActivity should be a Fragment that replace the Fragment in MainActivity.

Comment: @Weekend But I need to call "initializeFromIntent()" to start the barcodeView. This isn't possible in a Fragment, right?

Comment: @Sadik Maybe `getActivity().getIntent()`? Or, you may dig the source code of `initializeFromIntent()` to found what args are actually required. Normally they would be some `EXTRA_*`. Pass the args by `Fragment.setArgument()`, then set proper EXTRA_ in a `new Intent()`.

Comment: I have probably not described my problem well. When the MainActivity's `onCreate` method is executed, I don't have any Intent yet. So how would I be able to display the contents of my Camera in a Fragment inside the MainActivty, when calling the Camera itself is only possible with starting an Activity (via Intent)?